# Facebook Permissions iOS

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

So I was fiddling around with Facebook's iOS SDK and with it I managed to allow the user to login into my app. I had a `UIView` setup on the storyboard that was of `FBSDKLoginButton` class which according to [this](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit), its simply a subclass of `UIButton`. I then created an `@IBOutlet weak var facebookLogInBtn: FBSDKLoginButton!`. Then I went forth to setup my permissions as such

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    facebookLogInBtn.delegate = self
    facebookLogInBtn.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
}
```

This works just fine and accomplishes my desired task and any extra permissions I require, I simply append them to the `facebookLoginBtn.readPermissions` array. But after some Googling, I found a bunch of sites which use the `FBSDKGraphRequest` along with the `FBSDKLoginManager` instead. Take for instance this [blog](http://hoangtran.me/ios/development/2016/08/20/use-graph-api-to-retrieve-facebook-user-information-in-ios/). Now my questions are:

1. Is my way deemed acceptable or hacky? It works but I just want to be certain that I am following the standard procedures.
2. How does my way somehow tie into getting data through the Graph API? Because I am explicitly not declaring any `FBSDKRequest` or `FBSDKLoginManager` objects. I simply added my button then implemented its `delegates` and Voila! I am getting access. No need to parse any JSON data or anything.
3. I also noticed that most of these sites never actually made any of their `UIView` a class of `FBSDKLoginButton`. Could this be the reason why they have to handle everything 'manually'?

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.
Cheers!

Comment: Go to your FB account and remove permission from your account to this app. Then re sign in to the app. Is it working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that I was doing is correct but I wasn't able to retrieve any user data with it. With `FBSDKLoginManager` object, Facebook handled everything for me and it would simply return the user's final response (agreed or not) but without any actual data I requested through my `readPermissions` array. For any data retrieval; and possibly even writes, I had to create a `FBSDKGraphRequest` object for it. In summary, I ended up letting Facebook handle the log in and log out with `FBSDKLoginManager` and upon success, I retrieved user data with `FBSDKGraphRequest` as shown below

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!)
{
    if error != nil
    {
       print("Facebook Log In Failed")
       print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    let graphRequest: FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields" : "\(FacebookPermission.NAME), \(FacebookPermission.FIRST_NAME), \(FacebookPermission.LAST_NAME), \(FacebookPermission.EMAIL)"])

    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result:AnyObject!, error: NSError!) in

        if error == nil
        {
            print("Data retrieval was successful")
        }
        else
        {
            print("Facebook Graph Request Error")
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```